# validate hidden form element with jQuery Validation (for use with woocommerce reviews)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate a hidden form with the jQuery Validation plugin to work with woocommerce reviews.

The HTML output is:

```
<form>
<!-- then later -->
<div class="comment-form-rating-wrap"><p class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">Overall Rating</label><span class="required">*</span><p class="stars"><span><a class="star-1" href="#">1</a><a class="star-2" href="#">2</a><a class="star-3" href="#">3</a><a class="star-4" href="#">4</a><a class="star-5" href="#">5</a></span></p><select style="display: none;" name="rating" id="rating">
        <option value="">Rate…</option>
        <option value="5">Perfect</option>
        <option value="4">Good</option>
        <option value="3">Average</option>
        <option value="2">Not that bad</option>
        <option value="1">Very Poor</option>
    </select></p><div class="rating-error">select a rating</div><p></p></div>

</form>
```

As you can see there is a form element as above which is hidden, because the form instead displays stars (it's a product review) and it uses this jquery to hide the select element and change to stars:

```
        jQuery('#rating').hide().before('<p class="stars"><span><a class="star-1" href="#">1</a><a class="star-2" href="#">2</a><a class="star-3" href="#">3</a><a class="star-4" href="#">4</a><a class="star-5" href="#">5</a></span></p>');

jQuery('body')
    .on( 'click', '#respond p.stars a', function(){
        var jQuerystar   = jQuery(this);
        var jQueryrating = jQuery(this).closest('#respond').find('#rating');

        jQueryrating.val( jQuerystar.text() );
        jQuerystar.siblings('a').removeClass('active');
        jQuerystar.addClass('active');

        return false;
    })
    .on( 'click', '#respond #submit', function(){
        var jQueryrating = jQuery(this).closest('#respond').find('#rating');
        var rating  = jQueryrating.val();

    });
```

So the question is how do I link this to the jQuery Validation plugin?

Comment: I cleaned up the question a bit, and I don't see any reason to close it anymore.  OP - best not to edit in some variation of the answer.  Instead leave it to future readers to look through the answer(s), it should be clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're updating your hidden select each time a user clicks a star.  If that's the case, all you need to do is make sure that the hidden select is validated, and jQuery Validate will take care of the rest:

```
$('#theOverallForm').validate({
     ignore:[],
     rules: {
         rating:'required'
         //your other rules here
     }
});
```

The `ignore:[]` tells validate that you want it to validate hidden elements.

Keep the rest of your code about maintaining the state of the hidden select, but get rid of the code that does things on submit of the form, and deal with that in the `submitHandler` of validate.

Comment: OP says these are "non-form" elements... no `form` tags.

Comment: @Sparky - I suspect OP has just misspoken?  Or really, why not just slap some form tags around the whole thing... shouldn't hurt anything :)

Comment: I took that to mean "I want to validate these stars which are not form elements" instead of "there is no form"

Comment: I'm not really sure but you'd be surprised.  I answered at least one other question recently where the OP did not have/want form tags.

Comment: why do some people always take things literally :(

Anyway this works perfectly:

    ignore:[],
    rules: {
    rating:'required',
    }

Comment: @user1358120, don't knock people trying to help just because you can't write properly.  BTW, we are supposed to take the question literally, not make guesses about code you originally left out.